# Windows BATCH question mark as script parameter

Tags: windows, batch-file

I cannot figure out how to know if my script is called with a question mark (?)

For example I have `run.bat a b c ?`

```
SET /A argCount=0
FOR %%x IN (%*) DO (
    SET /A argCount+=1
    ECHO %%x
)
ECHO %argCount%
```

This prints as the following, **note that the question mark does not register as the 4th parameter**.

```
a
b
c
3
```

I also tried to call it with the following variations, the question mark just un-detectable.

```
run.bat a b c ?
run.bat a b c -?
run.bat a b c /?
```

How do I detect if there is a question mark as a script parameter?

Comment: Command line in Windows 7

Comment: Try quoting with backslash or double quotes: \? or "?"

Comment: `if "%4" equ "?" echo The fourth param is a question mark...`. Remember that a question mark _in a `for` command set_ work as a wild card!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, a plain `FOR` treats the content inside the parentheses as a set of files where * and ? are wildcards.

To avoid this you can treat it as a string instead and use the `FOR /F` token parsing and a loop or you can use the classic `SHIFT` command to enumerate the parameters:

```
@echo off
call :testbatch_recursiveFor a b c ?
ECHO %argCount%

call :testbatch_shift a b c ?
ECHO %argCount%
goto :EOF


:testbatch_recursiveFor
IF "%~1" == "" SET /A argCount=0
FOR /F "tokens=1,*" %%x IN ("%*") DO (
    ECHO arg:%%x
    CALL %0 %%y
    SET /A argCount+=1
)
GOTO :EOF

:testbatch_shift
SET /A argCount=0
:testbatch_shift_loop
IF NOT "%~1" == "" (
    ECHO arg:%1
    SET /A argCount+=1
    SHIFT
    GOTO testbatch_shift_loop
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you, the `SHIFT` command is more preferable in my case.